# Find serialVersionUID (bash: serialver: command not found)

Tags: java

I am trying to find out the serialVersionUID for a class which is on a tomee server using serialver command but when I try to run it, it says:

bash: serialver: command not found

I noticed that I have jre 1.7.0_51-b13 installed but don't have jdk installed. So, I might not be able to use serialver. Is there any other way I could find the serialVersionId just having the class file?

Everything is setup on a SUSE 11.0 server.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Why not run it on your development machine, which presumably does have the JDK?

Answer (score 0):

The `serialver` utility is only included in a JDK installation.  It is a development tool.

It is possible that there is some hacky way to transplant a copy of `serialver` into a machine that only has a JRE installed, but it is a bad idea for a number of reasons.

I haven't managed to track down any 3rd-party implementations of `serialver`; i.e. something that you could install independently of the JRE.  It should be possible to implement such a tool, but it would hard to justify the effort.

So, if you need to run `serialver`, my advice is to install a JDK.  (Disk space is cheap ...)